# If I remove my A record, will it mess up MX records on that domain?

Tags: domains, dns, google-workspace, mx

I am using DNSimple and S3/Cloudfront.

Following their recommended configuration looks like this:

```
myapex.com ------ REDIRECT --> www.myapex.com
www.myapex.com -- CNAME -----> lkj32lkj323323.cloudfront.net
```

This is all bacon gravy.

I'm about to make the change though, and I got nervous because I have a lot of existing MX records. They all point to Google services though, as we use Google for our email. Am I likely to break email or other services by removing an old `A` record? Do `MX` records do something special with the zone apex or `A` record?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***They all point to Google services though, as we use Google for our email. Am I likely to break email or other services by removing an old A record?***

If your [MX records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48090#J) remain pointed to the Google mail server hosts, then you should be fine, providing that your [nameservers](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48090#I) are reachable and DNS table contains those MX records.

As far as other "services", that really depends on if they're [A records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48090#H) or [CNAME records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48090#K), and where they point to. `CNAME` records point to hostnames, and `A` records point hostnames to IP addresses. So if you update or change the IP address of a hostname in an `A` record, the `CNAME` that points to them will resolve to the new IP address of the hostname. If you remove an `A` record for a hostname that a `CNAME` points to, then it will no longer resolve.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. All my CNAME records are mapped elsewhere. Now I just have some legacy A records that are pointed at subdomains. For example, I have `01.sendmail.mydomain.com` with an A record hanging around. Will a redirect for `mydomain.com` interfere with that?

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure I completely follow, but "redirects" are done at the web server-level (e.g., 301 redirects), and `A` records are at the DNS-level (before it reaches the web server). So if you have an `A` record pointing a subdomain somewhere, it shouldn't be impacted if the root domain is redirected elsewhere.

Comment: That's what I thought, too--I usually do redirects in Apache or at the application level, but DNSimple and others have what they call a "URL" record. It's a 301 redirect they say. I'm not sure how it's actually implemented.

Comment: For all who may follow, turns out an `A` record is resolved before a 301 or `URL` record. I had an old `A` record and a `URL` or redirect record and the `A` record was winning until I removed it.

Comment: Yes, a [URL record](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/url-record) is DNSimple's term for an HTTP redirect, which is a 301 redirect - see this [link](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/redirect). As commented above, an `A` record will be resolved before reaching a web server redirect.

Answer (score 1):

> Do MX records do something special with the zone apex or A record?

Your record for the root of your domain (`myapex.com` in your case) cannot be a CNAME record.  It should be an A record.  If this specific record is a CNAME record, mail will not be delivered to your MX records, rather it will be delivered to the MX records of where that CNAME points.

Other A records (to sub-domains) can be removed safely without affecting mail delivery or MX records.

Many CDN and load balancing services require that DNS record for your site be a CNAME to their DNS.  If you want to host your website without a www then this can be a problem.  I've been using Amazon Route 53 DNS services for this which introduce a new "Alias" type of DNS records where you specify the external name (like a CNAME) but they look up the address periodically and serve an IP address (A record): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html

Comment: My first CDN experience is exactly why I'm learning all this. The solution I've been told is to 301 the apex to www and cname your www to your CDN. I have implemented this and it works well.

Comment: Specifically, you would need to have an A record pointing to a web server that performs a redirect.    I personally don't like the "www" in my URLs, so this particular work-around pains me.